# Is it okay to call MutableLiveData's setValue's method rapildy?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, mutablelivedata

I have an EditText where I need to hold its value in a MutableLiveData in a viewmodel.
Is it okay to be calling the method setValue("the changed edittext string") every time the user edits something in the EditText?
The reason why I'm doing this is to keep the data alive even if the user for example rotated the screen.
Is there any other way to achieve the same result? Cause I feel like it can be expensive and it's a bad practice calling the method over and over. here's an example in an activity:

```
public class NoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityNoteBinding binding;
    private NoteViewModel viewmodel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_note);

        viewmodel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);

        addObservers();
        addListeners();
    }

    private void addObservers() {
        viewmodel.noteBodyLiveData.observe(this, s -> binding.noteBody.setText(s));
    }

    private void addListeners() {
        binding.noteBody.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                viewmodel.noteBodyLiveData.setValue(String.valueOf(s));
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
```

The LiveData Objects are initialized with the data corresponding to what's in the database.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what makes you think that this is "expensive" - you are simply updating a reference as the result of a callback, once updated the MutableLiveData triggers "notify obervers" (classic observer patern) - the only observer would be the single observer, which SHOULD guard against infinite looping - currently does not. It is not really "expensive" in terms of allocation (allocations of objects in use already exist) and cpu cycles / computation, however you should fix the infinite loop by checking equality before setting the text on the `view`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things out! Though, I should have been providing a more "expensive" example, such as a ```MutableLiveData``` holding a list of objects updated rapidly. In terms of looping, I thought there wouldn't be any with this approach, since one callback would be triggering the other, and the other won't be triggering the first one back again, because data hasn't been changed since its first trigger. Am I wrong here?

Comment: you where right, there is a loop, didn't know about ```setValue()``` would always trigger subscribed methods all the time even if there is no change.. Thanks!